# Why is Channel Images searching for images in the cache folder?

Tags: channel-images, cache

I cloned a site to overhaul it, meaning I copied over all files and databases, but following the instructions in the ExpressionEngine User Guide to upgrade (from 2.5.2 to 2.10.2) I cleared all caches.

I updated Channel Images to version 5.4.19, but when I try to regenerate images I get the following error (username and filename redacted):

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: copy(/home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/cache/channel_images/<filename>.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: local/local.php

Line Number: 111


Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Image file not found: /home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/cache/channel_images/<filename>__small.jpg' in /home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/libraries/PHPThumb/ThumbBase.inc.php:193 Stack trace: #0 /home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/libraries/PHPThumb/ThumbBase.inc.php(172): ThumbBase->triggerError('Image file not ...') #1 /home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/libraries/PHPThumb/ThumbBase.inc.php(110): ThumbBase->fileExistsAndReadable() #2 /home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/libraries/PHPThumb/GdThumb.inc.php(96): ThumbBase->__construct('/home/<username>/...', false) #3 /home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/libraries/PHPThumb/ThumbLib.inc.php(127): GdThumb->__construct('/home/<username>/...', Array, false) #4 /home/<username>/p in /home/<username>/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/libraries/PHPThumb/ThumbBase.inc.php on line 193
```

Why is it searching in the cache directory for the images? Shouldn't it just be searching for the original files in the `/images/uploads` directory? What are my options to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

ChannelImages can use locations local/cloudfiles/s3 to store images. When you regenerate images, it always fetches the image to cache. It then plays the actions and stores the versions back to the storage location.

The error is an issue with location/local/local.php in the method download_file(). (e.g. if the copy fails, it throws the warning (yet, still returns true))